# Publishing a WPF Application

Tags: .net, wpf, publish

I’m new to WPF, so I apologise if this is an obvious question.

I’m trying to publish a WPF application.  I’ve gone through the publish process and published it to my local host (http:/localhost/app).  Once it was published, it gave me the published URL: http://MyNetworkID/ProgramName/publish.htm.  There is a run icon here, but when I click it, it asks me how I want to open the WPF application.  I use Firefox as my default browser, and I get a choice of “Windows Presentation Foundation Host” or internet explorer.

If I select WPF Host, I just get the same question again.

If I select IE then it tells me that the application cannot be downloaded.  Error message in the log file is: “An exception occurred while downloading the manifest”.  If I navigate to the IIS directory (inetpub\wwroot\app\application files) then I can find a manifest file under the relevant version.

I’ve set-up the License and granted trusted permissions to the license holder (me), just in case it was that.  Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

Below is an extract from the error log:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* An exception occurred while downloading the manifest. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file:///C:/Documents and Settings/username/Local Settings/Temp/Application Files/WpfAppName_1_1_0_0/WpfAppName.exe.manifest did not succeed.
+ Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp\Application Files\WpfAppName_1_1_0_0\WpfAppName.exe.manifest'.
```

I checked, and there is no sub folder “Application Files” inside Temp.

Comment: I've had the same problem with localhost deployment. Could you post the content of the apllication manifest? Its a simple XML file.

Comment: I've updated my question - it appears that the problem is not with the manifest file, but that the file cannot be downloaded for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install an add-on for FireFox that can run ClickOnce applications, without it you can't run ClickOnce applications at all when FireFox is your default browser (not even when using IE).

.net 3.5 installed such an add-on but it was disabled by a FireFox update a while back, I can't find it on my machine and I don't have a ClickOnce app ready to test it.

A quick google search turns up the [FFClickOnce](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1608/) extension, but I've never tested it myself.

Comment: Thanks - I used IETab in the end

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was making an XBAP to import a local MS Access db into SQL server.  After much Googling, I found the solution:I needed to add a certificate to my Certificate Manager that granted full trust.  Sounds like you have the same problem.
[Here are detailed instructions](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx)

Comment: No - this is a different problem.  My application has already been granted full trust.

Comment: @pm_2 but did you add a certificate?